# React protect admin panel using JsonWebToken

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router, jwt

I got a single page app written with React and ReactRouter and the frontend seems to be easy going. 
But I have no idea how to design a backend which is only accessable by admins. On the server-side I use a NodeJS / Express RESTful API which uses JWT (JsonWebToken) for authentication. 
Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Express Middleware to check and validate JWT. If the JWT is valid then proceed with the API otherwise redirect to login. There are lots of articles available on ExpressJs site about middleware.

Comment: Do I have to reach to the server for every request on the client?

Comment: Express middleware is a server side to execute anything before the endpoint is called. For React client side you can implement simple redux and react-router composition

Answer (score 0):

One great option is [express-jwt](https://github.com/auth0/express-jwt)

You import it, make a middleware, and place it before any protected route. If the token is valid, req.user will be set with the JSON object decoded to be used by later middleware for authorization and access control.

```
    const jwt = require("express-jwt");
    const auth = jwt({
      secret: jwt_secret
    });

router.get("/secret/:uid", auth, profileCtrl.secret);
```